# How can I use transaction in this code?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was trying to use this code without transaction but it gave me error, so I want to use it with transaction. How I can use it?

My code is:

```
SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");

SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adapt;

private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "insert into users(Name, Password) values('ubaid', 'ali')";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your error is not because of lack of transaction. And you do not need a transaction when you just do one operation, the database engine already does one internally.

Comment: `but it gave me error ` You think your question is clear now?

Comment: @Crowcoder but without transaction data is not updating also not giving any error, it just shows record updated actually its not updated

Comment: @L.B I mean insert query is not updating my database, even when I execute my query it return 2 not 0 which means query applied successfully,

Comment: There could be an ambient transaction in progress, there is no way to tell from this code snippet. If you need to enlist this in an existing transaction then that is different than creating a new one.

Comment: @Crowcoder how i can stop running any transaction ?

Comment: If you had a reference to it you would commit or rollback like Karsharp4U is showing but if you don't have a reference to it then I don't know the best way, you may have to run some T-SQL script to kill it but I'm sure that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Restart your sql service, maybe you did some mistake and all you need to do is clear out transactions.

Comment: @Crowcoder then any other solution ?

Comment: There is always a solution, you just do not provide enough context to provide it. That is one reason you have been getting downvotes. There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, so the problem is completely unknown.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes bro u r right all are saying show complete code but i swear its complete insertion code, i have no other code than display method where select query is working fine, so what can i do ? am sitting without eating any thing since 12hours but problem is not solve able. tell me which code i have to show ?

Comment: Start with the error message. (Edit the question, don't put it in comments)

Comment: @Crowcoder am using c#'s service based database. is this problem ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use MSSQL Server, SqlExpress or LocalDB, they all work. Why can't you show the errror?

Comment: @Crowcoder Respected Brother No error occur,no expectation raise, i receive message "Record Updated Successfully" but when i check manually in DataBase no new record inserted

Comment: Your question says you get an error when you don't use a transaction. Not seeing an update in the database can be many things, like maybe you are not looking in the same database that your code is actually hitting.

Comment: I do most dev on Web apps so not familiar with MessageBox - Does the `MessageBox.Show` method halt the thread until the message is cleared? Could that be why the insert is not yet committed?

Comment: No, but we have not definitely determined we have a problem with transactions at all. Did you say the query returns `2`? Is there a trigger on the users table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adapt;
SqlTransaction trans;

private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        trans = con.BeginTransaction();     // Begins transaction

        string query = "insert into users(Name,Password)values('ubaid','ali')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        con.Close();

        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //error occurred
    {
        trans.Rollback();  // Rollback transaction on error
    }
}
```

Try the above code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @kashap4u at line trans.Rollback(); Null Reference was un handled

Comment: @Alex is c# 's service based database sql express server ?